# Windows 10 cannot see shared files on Mac

Tags: macos, windows-10, lan

I have a brand new PC running Windows 10. This machine does not have a wireless card, but does have an ethernet port. I have an existing Mac Pro tower that has a wireless card and 2 ethernet ports.

I am using the Mac to connect to my wireless network. I have enabled Internet Sharing on the Mac, and I am able to log into the Internet with the PC. So far so good.

I have also enabled file sharing on the Mac. I am able to log into the PC from the Mac, but not the other way around. I need to be able to log into the Mac, which has 12TB of storage, from the PC.

The network connection is definitely working, but neither the Mac or the shared volumes are showing in the PC finder.

I have been researching this for a couple of hours and everything looks good.

What am I missing here? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Admittedly this is an edge case, but through a bit of testing I found the solution.

On the Mac

- My Mac has 2 Ethernet ports, labelled Ethernet 1 and
  Ethernet 2.
- I connected the PC to Ethernet 1 with a standard (not
  crossover) cable.
- In the Mac System Preferences> Sharing, I enabled
  'Internet Sharing' from Wi-Fi to port Ethernet 1.
- In the Mac System
  Preferences> Sharing, I enabled 'File Sharing'
- In the Mac System
  Preferences> Network, I selected 'Using DHCP' from the Configure IPv4
  dropdown.

  - I also noted the IP address displayed just below.

Moving to the PC

- At the search bar, type 'Command Prompt"
- At the Command Prompt type `ipconfig /all`

  - Note the DNS Server address
- At the search bar, type in 'Change Ethernet Settings'
- On the right menu, select 'Change Adapter options'
- Right click the appropriate Ethernet selection and select 'Properties'
- Select the option 'Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IP v4) and click on 'Properties'

  - Leave the top selector at 'Obtain an IP address automatically'
  - Select the lower option 'Use the following DNS server addresses'
  - Add these values:
  - Preferred DNS Server: the value that you noted from the PC Command Prompt DNS server address
  - Alternate DNS Server: the value that you noted from the Mac Ethernet 1 IP Address

You should be up and running now, and your Mac folders should be available from the Windows file browser. You can confirm the additional DNS address by returning to the PC Command Prompt and running `ipconfig /all` again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable *File Sharing*. Open the System Preferences app, and go to Sharing. Click on the checkbox to enable File Sharing.

**In addition**, you may have to click Options and check the checkbox for each account you want to be shared.